# unable to run a binary in mac,running on Linux

Tags: linux, macos

I am using a software for graph mining.
I have got the binary of that software in 2 folders for Linux mode and SunOs mode but don't have the source.
I am able to run the binary in Linux machine.
But when I want to run the binary in a Mac machine I am getting "command not found" for both the Linux and SunOs folders' binaries.

Could someone suggest if it can be able to run this in a MAC machine by any means like using a Linux shell or something

Gaurav

EDIT:I am getting "cannot execute binary" error when I set chmod to "u+x"

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to recompile it for OS X or use a VM.

A command not found just means you're not executing it right, make sure it's `chmod u+x` and it's either on your `PATH`, or you specify the path explicitly.

Comment: i did the chmod and i am getting the error "cannot execute binary file" .i dont have the source and just have the binary

Comment: @gaurav That will be an issue. You could try running a Linux image in a VM. It may work if compiled for x86.

Comment: will fink/Mac port serve my purpose

Comment: @gaurav Or brew, if it's available on any of them, of course.

Comment: @gaurav Short answer: Only if it's portable and re-compiled for the architecture.  Long answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3322/what-makes-osx-programs-not-runnable-on-linux/3350#3350

Answer (score 3):

If you use the file command you will see the difference, on the linux executable you'll have something like:

> ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically
>   linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, not stripped

and something like this for OS X executables:

> command: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures command (for
>   architecture x86_64): Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64 command (for
>   architecture i386):   Mach-O executable i386

Comment: hmm..this is the text i m getting ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.0.30, stripped   I also have a SUNOs binary .Can this be of some help    ELF 32-bit MSB executable, SPARC, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped

Answer (score 0):

Operating systems generally don't support executing object code any extra formats... If Mac osx decended from solaris or Linux, then there could be some incentive for legacy support. But just assume everything to be binarily incomparable if it was compiled for a different arch and platform. There are a few places where you inherit backwards compatibility, running 32 but code on 64 bit oses... Or ppc code support on intel macs, but I suspect that both of those, especially the latter were non trivial engineering tasks.

Here are your options...
Get the source and compile on the Mac, if it compiles on Linux and solaris good chance it will compile and run ok on Mac.

Run through an emulator or boot camp